# How to code this LINQ query in a better way

Tags: c#, linq

I have one LINQ Query. I dont know much about LINQ. I was working on Entity Framework. I have to get the records based on the Input Date (CDate). Assume the structure is something like this.

```
          Table A                                Table B

       Id          CDate                   Id            No         A_Id

       1          11-11-2012                1            1001         1
       2          11-11-2012                2            1002         1
       3          12-12-2012                3            1003         2
```

Based on this table definition if the input date is some like 11-11-2012, the output should be like,

```
    Table B

    Id        No

     1        1001
     2        1002
     3        1003
```

something like the above. I have tried this one but its not working. Pls have a look at this code.

**Code**

```
     var model = (from x in Db.TableB
                  where x.TableA.CDate == 'Input Value'    // 11-11-2012
                         select new ViewModel
                         {
                         }).Tolist();
```

Please tell me the possibilities that i can write code to get the Distinct value for the appropriate input date.

Thanks,

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want some thing like this?

```
var model = (from x in Db.TableB
     join y in Db.TableB on x.ID equals y.ID
     where x.TableA.CDate == 'Input Value' //11.11.2012
     select new  
     {  
         x.ID,
         y.No 
     }).ToList();
```

Output:

```
Id        No

 1        1001
 2        1002
```

**UPDATE**

```
var model = (from x in Db.TableB
            where x.TableA.CDate == 'Input Value' //11.11.2012
            select new  
            {  
                x.ID,
                x.No 
            }).ToList();
```

Sorry, first, I thought there is one-to-one relationship. But your entity has one-to-many relationships. Your codes are correct, only add

```
select new  
{  
     x.ID,
     x.No 
}).ToList();
```

Comment: The join is probably unnecessary; OP already has `x.TableA.CDate` so it looks like the entities come with a reference to their parent item.

Comment: Yes. I just saw it.there is one-to-many relation ship. I thought one-to-one. I will update my answer.